# SQL query to select records of two tables without condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

if table1 has

```
 id name
----------
 1  bala
 2  nara
```

and table2 has

```
 id name
-----------
 1  hari
 2  nara
 3  john
```

i want result has

```
 id name
-----------
 1  bala
 2  nara
 1  hari
 2  nara
 3  john
```

can anybody tell me SQL query for this please...

Comment: Use UNION ALL clause

Answer (score 8):

You could use **`UNION ALL`**.

**Query**

```
select [id], [name] from [table1]
union all
select [id], [name] from [table2];
```

Comment: @BalajiChandraSekaran : Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem.